# jQuery-File-Upload on click and response

Tags: jquery

I'm using the [jQuery-File-Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) but I'm having trouble associating it with a click and generating a response. After I select a file, it automatically uploads to a folder (so at least it's working), but I'd prefer to have it upload upon clicking a button.

Additionally, I need the server to return an ID after the image is uploaded to the database, but I can't seem to get a response.

I've been working on this all day and it's a bit frustrating, but I can't find any other jQuery plugins like this that are updated. If you have an alternative, I'd appreciate it.

Here's the code:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/file/upload', array('id' => 'fileupload'));?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" multiple />

    <button id="upload_file" type="button" class="btn btn-primary start">
        <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Start upload
   </button>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>assets/admin/js/fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>assets/admin/js/fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>assets/admin/js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>assets/admin/js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: $('#fileupload').attr('action'),
    replaceFileInput: false,
    add: function (e, data) {
         data.submit();
     }

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: consider uploadify as an alternative

Comment: I messed with Uploadify a bit. It's tricky to get working with Codeigniter though. I'll keep trying it with tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest uplodify too. But have you looked into the callback methods?

```
.bind('fileuploadcompleted', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
```

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

If you want it to work after you've clicked a button, you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
function uploadMe() { 
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    autoUpload:false,
    url:$('#fileupload').attr('action'),
    replaceFileInput:false,
    add:function(e, data){
      data.submit();
    }
  });
}

$(".icon-upload").click(uploadMe);
```

Sorry I haven't tested it.

Comment: I thought that would work too, but it doesn't for some reason.